# Migrating from cakephp 3.x to cakephp 4.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I Have a CakePhP Project in version 3.x and I want to migrate it to 4.x, is it possible?

What are the steps to follow to migrate from 3.x to 4.x CakePhp version

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please add you questions in a comment sections of each answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can check on this step by step guide from the official site of CakePHP

[4.0 Upgrade Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html)